# How to switch animations between onActivityStart and onBackPressed events?

Tags: android, android-animation

Due to some features of the design of my application I need to start new activity on `onBackPressed` event.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is that it looks like user proceeds in the deep of application - not like user returns back.

So, just for that case I need to switch animations. I know about `overridePendingTransition`, but how to get system default animations (`activityCloseEnterAnimation` and others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    TypedArray activityStyle = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {android.R.attr.windowAnimationStyle});
    int windowAnimationStyleResId = activityStyle.getResourceId(0, 0);
    activityStyle.recycle();

    activityStyle = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(windowAnimationStyleResId, new int[] {android.R.attr.activityCloseEnterAnimation, android.R.attr.activityCloseExitAnimation});
    int activityCloseEnterAnimation = activityStyle.getResourceId(0, 0);
    int activityCloseExitAnimation = activityStyle.getResourceId(1, 0);
    activityStyle.recycle();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    overridePendingTransition(activityCloseEnterAnimation, activityCloseExitAnimation);
}
```